# On what specific time are ubuntu versions made public?

Tags: 11.04, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At which time will the upcoming Ubuntu release be made available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65476/at-which-time-will-the-upcoming-ubuntu-release-be-made-available)

On what specific time are Ubuntu versions normally released?

10.10 was released at 10:10.10 but that's the only version I know of that has a time specification.