# What time can I start downloading Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At what time will the upcoming Ubuntu release be made available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65476/at-what-time-will-the-upcoming-ubuntu-release-be-made-available)

I was wondering at what time I'd be able to start my Ubuntu 12.04 download! I am competing with my friend as to who'll get it first! Please help!